# Accessing offset storage from the connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a source connector written in Java running is distributed mode with
`offset.storage.topic = connect-offsets`. The topic is populated when tasks are committing. From my task class (extends org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceTask) I can read this topic by using `context.offsetStorageReader()`.

Is there a way to read the offset from within my connector class?

When starting or restarting the connector, I want to be able to use this information to decide how to assign partitions to tasks. I normally have a small number of 'new' partitions and a large number of 'old' partitions, I *need* to assign all the new partitions to the same task but 'old' partitions can be assigned to any task. Knowing whether an entry exist for a partition would let me figure out which tasks are 'new' (offset topic has no entry) and which are 'old' (offset topic has an entry).

Comment: You can do by using context(SourceTaskContext class). Something like, context.offsetStorageReader().offset(partition), this will return you a map and then you can pass your "offset" key to it to retrieve offset.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this easily. In the end it became a moot point because I changed my connector so that the offset was not part of the the partition-to-task assignment decision.